# Can I disable pinch to show all open tabs in Safari?

Tags: safari, trackpad, settings

Too often, when I try to move my cursor and click, or try to drag something or select text, and my two fingers end up on the trackpad at the same time, all my open tabs shrink into this view:

[image]

This is extremely disruptive as it makes me lose my focus and then I have to locate the page I was currently on, click it and then resume working.

I can't tell what this specific feature in **Safari** is called (I want to still be able to pinch to zoom in and out of a page), and couldn't find info anywhere on how to completely disable it.

### ***Can I disable this? (or I can use another browser, obviously...)***

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with it for a month and then ended up switching back to Chrome - it solved the issue